# The remainder of Taylor (Maclaurin) series of $\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

Something is bothering me with the remainder of the Taylor (Maclaurin) series of $\cos(x)$.
The formula of $a_n$ is $(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.
By Leibniz Theorem, $r_n<a_{n+1}$ which is, $\frac{x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}$. The Lagrange remainder is $r_n= \frac{f^{(2n+1)}(c) \cdot x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. My question is, knowing that $f^{2n+1}(x)=0$ when $x=0$. Can we say that $r_n=r_{n+1}$ and take the lagrange remainder to be $r_n= \frac{f^{(2n+2)}(c) \cdot x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}$?

Thank you,
Shir

Answer (score 1):

The textbook "An introduction to numerical methods and analysis" by James F. Epperson, 2nd edition, page 3:

$$
\cos x = 1 - \frac{1}{2!}x^2 + \frac{1}{4!}x^4 + \dotsm + \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n+2} \cos \xi_x
$$

So the answer is yes, because the first term for remainder is zero then you can go for the next n.

Comment: Why is $f^{(2n+1)}(c)$ taken to be zero in the remainder? According to the formula, it's a sine function at $x=c$ and not at $x=0$.